# Using jvm.h from JNI

Tags: java, c++, jvm, java-native-interface

At the moment I am using the libraries within JAVA_HOME/include in my JNI application. This consists of

- classfile_constants.h
- jawt.h
- jdwpTransport.h
- jni.h
- jvmti.h
- jvmticmlr.h
- windows/jawt_md.h
- windows/jni_md.h
- windows/bridge/AccessBridgeCallbacks.h
- windows/bridge/AccessBridgeCalls.c
- windows/bridge/AccessBridgeCalls.h
- windows/bridge/AccessBridgePackages.h

While these offer me a lot of control, I really want to be able to call the actual C++ functions defined in hotspot source code. I looked at the JDK 8 source code and found that `src/share/javavm/export` contained lots more header files, such as jvm.h with much more powerful functions.

I tried including these in my project but I get a `unresolved external symbol` error, likely because these header files dont contain the actual function definitions.

How can I use these kind of functions in my JNI code base? Is it even possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't include "thank you in advance" or similar. See here for more info: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions declared in `jvm.h` are for internal JDK use only. They are not supposed to be called from user code. They are not a part of any public API, and they can change in any (even minor) JDK update.

It is possible to call these functions, either by linking your binary against libjvm, or by using dynamic lookup, i.e. [`dlopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) / [`dlsym`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html), but the use of undocumented API is highly discouraged and makes you JNI code not portable between different JDK versions and/or builds.

Comment: Thank you very much. One last question: Do you know if its possible to find the pointer to an already resolved native method? For example `ClassLoader.findBuiltinLib(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;`. I know how to use the jvmti NativeMethodBind to find the pointer as they are resolved, but not if they have already been resolved.

Comment: @cookiedragon.234 This is a normal JNI method which follows regular JNI naming rules. You need to find the address of `Java_java_lang_ClassLoader_findBuiltinLib` function, and this can be done with `dlsym`.